# How to retrieve linkedin api in android other informations such like work experience

Tags: android, information-retrieval, linkedin-j

I saw that you have to use make new url "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(positions:(company:(name)))" but how to implement it, I always get unauthorized in return

Comment: Please include your code and the response from API you're getting.

Comment: public class LinkedInConnectActivity extends Activity {
 URL url = new URL("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(positions:(company:(name))");

Comment: it always says unauthorized in back.. can you provide the whole process on how to retrieve your work experience / positions on your linkedin information.. because im new to linkedin api, and I only retrieve headline, first name, lastname, but I need more than that information.. if you show me how... that will help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is my code snippet to get Work Experience:

Person p = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet.of(
                            ProfileField.ID, ProfileField.FIRST_NAME,
                            ProfileField.LAST_NAME, ProfileField.HEADLINE,ProfileField.EDUCATIONS,
                            ProfileField.INDUSTRY, ProfileField.PICTURE_URL,ProfileField.INTERESTS,
                            ProfileField.DATE_OF_BIRTH, ProfileField.LOCATION_NAME,ProfileField.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
                            ProfileField.SKILLS,ProfileField.POSITIONS,
                            ProfileField.MAIN_ADDRESS, ProfileField.LOCATION_COUNTRY));

Positions positions =p.getPositions();
                    for (Position position : positions.getPositionList()) {
                        linkedinInfo=linkedinInfo+" :\n"+position.getCompany().getName();
                    }
```